# Python Regex generic Solution

Tags: python, regex

I need to split this string into a dictionary to look something like this.Please note that the order of keys in the string may not be same.

```
String = 'Specialty: "Neurology: Neurology, NeuroScience", Profession: Nurse Practitioner, Source: TestSource'

Dict = { 'Specialty': "Neurology: Neurology, NeuroScience", 'Profession': 'Nurse Practitioner', 'Source': 'TestSource' }
```

A regex solution to this problem will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest would be with a proper parser, like `pyparsing` (`pip install pyparsing`):

```
from pyparsing import *

text = 'Specialty: "Neurology: Neurology, NeuroScience", Profession: Nurse Practitioner, Source: TestSource'

word = Word(alphas)
key = word + Suppress(':')
words = Combine(word + ZeroOrMore(" " + word))
value = (QuotedString('"') ^ words) + Optional(Suppress(', '))

dictionary = dictOf(key, value)

print dictionary.parseString(text).asDict()
# => {'Source': 'TestSource', 'Profession': 'Nurse Practitioner', 'Specialty': 'Neurology: Neurology, NeuroScience'}
```

We define a grammar that defines a `word` as series of letters, a `key` as a word followed by a colon (that we won't take into account), `words` as a string consisting of a word possibly with more of word separated by spaces, `value` as either words or a string quoted by double quotes possibly ending in a comma (that we don't want), and a `dictionary` as a list of key and value pairs. Then we let the parser do its thing.

EDIT: But I guess if you really want a regexp solution...

```
print {m[0]: m[1] or m[2]
    for m in re.findall(r'([^,:\s]+): (?:"([^"]*)"|([^,]+))', text)}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and efficient response using regex. Is there a reference that you could tag so that I can understand what you've written.

Comment: It's a bit complex to explain in the answer; https://regex101.com/r/zIPZcE/2 will give you a nice, colour-coded breakdown on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move this way:

```
def create_dict(string, splitter=',', dict_splitter=':'):
    _dict = {}

    temp = ([s for s in string.split(splitter)])

    for item in temp:
        key = item.split(dict_splitter)[0]
        value = item.split(dict_splitter)[1]
        _dict[key] = value

    return _dict

string = 'Specialty: "Neurology; Neurology NeuroScience", Profession: Nurse Practitioner, Source: TestSource'

_dict = create_dict(string)

for k, v in _dict.items():
    print(k, '\t', v)


 #  Output must be like this

 #   Specialty    "Neurology; Neurology NeuroScience"
 #  Profession   Nurse Practitioner
 #  Source       TestSource
```

Comment: You can't just arbitrarily ignore the fact that there is a comma in `"Neurology: Neurology, NeuroScience"`.

Comment: @Amadan, yeah, so that's why I said to move this way. Good answer btw